# Lua timed mouse macro (logiteck api)

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

logiteck api (http://www.wolfpack.pe.kr/attachment/1180489860.pdf)
trying to make a mouse script that presses a button for a certain amount of time and then makes a turn 180 degrees ingame: However not being sure of what my mouse sensitivity will be i want to make it adapt to my mouse sensitivity so:

1. when I press right button to begins to turn right until I release it stores the number of repeats for that turn in the `i` variable
2. it holds that variable for the second function where the program initially press "w" for me to move (unimportant) and then has a small delay (the small for loop). My player walks for that delay and then the `i` variable is used to simulate that exact turn I made before

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
i=1
                repeat
i=i +1
                    MoveMouseRelative(3,0)
                    Sleep(5)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
                  end

end

function oniEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
PressKey( "w" );

repeat
u=0
j=1

for k=1,999,1 do j=j/2 
////delay////
 end 

repeat
u=u + 1 
                    MoveMouseRelative(3,0)
                    Sleep(5)
                until  u==i




until  not IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )
ReleaseKey( "w" );


end
end
```

Problem: when I press <kbd>numlock</kbd> it does even start pressing "w"

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding.

Defining a function does nothing but to define that function.
The code in its body is only executed if you call the function.

As you only define `oniEvent`, but never call it, your code does what is to be expected: nothing.

If you want to react to mouse or key input you have to implement that in the `OnEvent` function which serves as the event handler and is called automatically whenever there is an event.

Please read the manual again. There are plenty of examples.